# YUI: load content with ajax into scrollable div without moving div content

Tags: javascript, yui, scroller

i am trying to do same as facebook do with messaging. First, scroll is place on the bottom of page instead of top (default behavior). When you scroll to top of div new messages are loaded but without change position of div content. Facebook only recalculate scroll position. So, when i load new messages on the top of scrollable div i need to stop scroll to automactily move scrollbar on the top of page.

I am using YUI JS library.... Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to make a

```
 scroll(0,0);
```

when the page finished loading new message content.

You also have to make a

```
 Y.one("scrollzone").syncUI();
```

to make YUI recalculate the height of the scrollable div.